# Android Camera2 issue

Tags: android

I am developing android app using camera2 api. I am getting following crash sometimes for some reason.

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: LegacyCameraCallback
    Process: com.vuro, PID: 5793
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.getSurfaces()' on a null object reference
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onCaptureErrorLocked(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2276)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onDeviceError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1914)
        at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim$CameraCallbackThread$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
E/AWSKeyValueStore: com.amazonaws.internal.keyvaluestore.KeyNotFoundException: Error occurred while accessing AndroidKeyStore to retrieve the key for keyAlias: com.amazonaws.mobile.client.aesKeyStoreAlias
I/AWSKeyValueStore: Deleting the encryption key identified by the keyAlias: com.amazonaws.mobile.client.aesKeyStoreAlias
I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 0 results from 22
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5793 SIG: 9

If anyone has experience in this crash, Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Post your code as well.